# Запуск сервера Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

Как запустить сервер Jetty? Можно ли это сделать из IDE Eclipse? Если можно, то как?

Пример с HelloWorld на сайте https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld мне не совсем понятен.
Я написал код, подключил нужные библиотеки. Когда запускаю - ничего не происходит.

В консоли Eclipse такие строки:

> 2015-06-15 01:09:04.047:INFO::main: Logging initialized @659ms
>   2015-06-15 01:09:04.219:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.9.v20150224
>   2015-06-15 01:09:04.656:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@45fe3ee3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
>   2015-06-15 01:09:04.661:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1264ms

Когда ввожу в браузере http://localhost:8080 - ничего не происходит.

Comment: ничего не происходит это что значит? "страница не найдена" пишет или пустая страница? вообще в логах смотрите что сервер пишет

Comment: Каким образом вы запустили приложение - скомпилировали в war и положили в директорию webapps?

Comment: В прямом смысле ничего не происходит, начинает грузить страницу и все.Никаких ошибок, ничего.
Запускал из Eclipse -> Run

Answer (score 1):

По логам видно, что сервер стартовал. Скорее всего либо нет стартовой страницы либо же же сервер стартовал на другом порте (например 8088 или 8082) - смотрите настройки сервера - куда он смотрит.

Comment: в логе выше 8080